# Python: How to make Selenium Webdriver click one element that appears first from 2 elements?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have two element locators, I want Selenium Webdriver to click on the element that is displayed first but am having trouble.

```
class SeleniumExtended:

def __init__(self, driver):
    self.driver=driver
    self.default_timeout=15

def wait_and_click_on_1_of_2_elements(self, locator, locator2,  timeout=None):
    timeout = timeout if timeout else self.default_timeout

    WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(locator or locator2)).click()
```

The problem with this is that it waits for 'locator1' and if it doesn't find it after 15 seconds it will start waiting for 'locator2'

I want it to click on one of these locators as soon as they are displayed. After only one of these locators is clicked than it can move on to whatever is next.

Comment: Did you try `EC.any_of(EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator), EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator2))`? I'm assuming it's the same result as what you've already got.

Comment: EC.any_of(EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator), EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator2))

actually worked for me! thank you

Comment: I've updated my answer below with this info if you want to accept it as the answer.

Comment: The any_of() sort of worked for me. It does click the first element it sees. But clicks it twice. I need it to click it once. Is that possible?

Comment: Check your code. I didn't write any code to click and `.any_of()` should only return a single element if you are using the code in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
EC.any_of(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator), 
    EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator2))
```

and see if that works.

If not, you can combine the two locators into one with an "OR" equivalent. Given the HTML below,

```
<div id="button1">Button1</div>
<div id="button2">Button2</div>
```

If you want to click either Button1 or Button2, you can make a CSS selector,

```
#button1, #button2
```

or XPath,

```
//*[@id='button1'] | //*[@id='button2']
```

and then wait for the one locator to be clickable.

---

NOTE: If you are going to wait for something and click it, use `EC.element_to_be_clickable()` instead of `EC.visibility_of_element_located()`.